# How do I convert a PDF stored as NSData to a CGPDFPageRef?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Please see the following code:

```
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"]; 
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
```

How do I convert myData to a CGPDFPageRef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [`CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL)?

Comment: yes I was able to get the required result from CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);   thanks again